# Do Sequential Monte Carlo simulations degenerate when you chain them together?

Tags: bayesian, sequential-monte-carlo

Context: Suppose that I run a Sequential Monte Carlo simulation with likelihood tempering to perform parameter inference on a filtering problem. This takes me from my (unspecified) prior distribution to a particle approximation of the posterior distribution on the model parameters.

Question: Can I use this posterior distribution as the prior for a new simulation? How? What are the pitfalls?

Motivating example: Suppose that a first SMC simulation uses uniform priors to estimate credible model parameters. Suppose that a second SMC simulation then takes this parameter distribution and conditions it on a new batch of data. The marginal likelihood of the first simulation would have little value, coming from uniform priors, but the marginal likelihood of the second simulation might represent goodness-of-fit for the model.

Thoughts: Generally speaking it seems valid to reuse a posterior distribution as the prior for further inference. However, the specific particle approximation produced by SMC seems problematic: once the likelihood tempering process has completed the particles seem unlikely to produce good proposals for further inference e.g. based on random-walk MCMC rejuvenation steps. The particles will be too sparsely distributed to detect changes in the distribution.

If that is accurate then I wonder how one can better rejuvenate the particles? Do you need to rerun the earlier SMC simulation(s) to ensure a smooth series of bridging distributions? Or do you introduce a new proposal distribution that covers more of the parameter space in between particles from the prior simulation? Or...?

Comment: On a theoretical groud, using the posterior given a first data set $x$ as the prior when analysing a second data set $y$ is correct. In practice, a natural form of tempering is including a portion of data at each iteration (Chopin, 2002) so this is working in general.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to (Chopin, 2002.) I have been gradually exploring the SMC literature for some time now but this is by far the paper that most directly addresses my problem of interest. Black box inference for static models based on likelihood function, automatic priors, data arriving in batches, successive marginal likelihood estimates. Great stuff!